# python выдает ошибку при скачивании colorama

Tags: python, pip, colorama

Пишу в терминал pip install colorama, выдает:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install colorama
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Макбук

Answer (score 1):

`pip install colorama`

Это команда рассчитанная на выполнение в терминале, консоли или командной строке (это одно и тоже)

Вы написали эту команду в специальном `Python` терминале `Python Shell` или в редакторе кода и она воспринимается как `Python` программа. Отсюда и возникает ошибка

Для выполнения используйте Терминал:
[image]